# Where should I keep read-write locks for each object in a list?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Where should I maintain locks on each object in a list?

Example:

> I have many different `Indicator` objects.
>
> My `Indicator` objects keep some state which can be updated
>   'in-flight', i.e. I want to grab any particular indicator in a list,
>   write-lock it and update it. I don't want to lock it unnecessarily for
>   reads, so I'd like to keep read-write locks on them.

Where shall I keep the locks? Shall I keep them in a map, mapped by the object id?

Maybe if I keep a map of locks mapped by the object itself, then that suffices for a list of `Indicator` as well as the locks (but I'm concerned there are issues I haven't hit yet with thread-safety if the objects are all in the keySet of the map).

Or maybe make the lock an attribute of the Indicator class?

Or is the overhead so negligible I should just lock on each object with `synchronized`?

Comment: You definitely don't want to have locks packed together and causing false sharing.

Comment: If you have a choice, you should keep locks with the object itself.  Either use `synchronized` as you suggest or compose the `Indicator` with a ReadWriteLock or other lock as appropriate.  Or make Holder object which hold both the `Indicator` and the lock.  A Map is probably a last ditch idea, only if you have no other choice.

Comment: @Leeor can you expand on that?

Comment: Well, it depends on how you implement the lock structure, but let's say it's an array indexed by object id, and that a lock is 8 bytes large. This means 8 consecutive locks share the same cache line, and a thread polling or acquiring for one would unintentionally invalidate all other locks from the other cores holding them (plus adjacent cache lines if your HW prefetcher decides so). This won't break functionality, but fetching the cache lines back every time would have a perf impact.

Comment: The first question should be whether you actually need a lock for each object of that list. Try to you explain why you think you need it. Perhaps, you drop the relevant information needed for choosing the best strategy while explaining the rationale.

Comment: @markspace I'll take that comment as an answer and put the lock on the Indicator class. A holder object sounds good too.